# svg scroll perfomance in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, svg, viewbox

I wrote a simple drag-n-scroll svg ([svg file](http://pastebin.com/raBms6YE), [code](http://pastebin.com/etm5vNht)). Here I move a viewBox of the picture after the mice.
And tested it in chromium and firefox.
In chromium it works nice (drags picture by mouse pointer). But in firefox it twitches on the same machine.
What is the reason, of this low performance? 
How can i overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to put evt.preventDefault(); in the event handlers to prevent the default drag/drop handling from being invoked.

Comment: I've just inserted this line into every handler, but it changes nothing. :(